# Can I create a SharePoint 2016 trial VM with "Developer Program Benefit" subscription on Azure?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2016

I have "Developer Program Benefit" subscription, would like to know if I can create a SharePoint 2016 trial VM on Azure for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint license seems to be 'Free' but you would nevertheless pay for the VMs hosting SharePoint.

You can find the pricing details here - [SharePoint Virtual Machine pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/sharepoint/).